# Convert Apex method to Batch

Tags: apex, trigger, batch

I want to convert this method to Batch Apex

```
public void Visibility() {
        Map<Id, List<Id>> accountContactRelationIdsMap = new Map<Id, List<Id>>();

        for (AccountContactRelation accountContactRelation : (List<AccountContactRelation>) Trigger.new) {
            String oldRoles = (Trigger.isUpdate) ? ((AccountContactRelation) Trigger.oldMap.get(accountContactRelation.Id)).Roles : null;
            
            if (accountContactRelation.Roles != null && accountContactRelation.Roles.contains(labelVisibilitePortail) && (Trigger.isInsert ||
                    (Trigger.isUpdate && (oldRoles == null || !oldRoles.contains(labelVisibilitePortail))))) {
                if (!accountContactRelationIdsMap.containsKey(accountContactRelation.AccountId)) {
                    accountContactRelationIdsMap.put(accountContactRelation.AccountId, new List<Id>());
                }
                accountContactRelationIdsMap.get(accountContactRelation.AccountId).add(accountContactRelation.ContactId);
 ?
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a few minutes to read [how to ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/322233/edit) your question to demonstrate what you have tried and where you are specifically stuck.

Comment: To find out more about writing Batchables, see [this trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_batch). This should give you enough information to let you convert your code to a batch.

Comment: Thanks , i have read that trailhead but i still didn't know how to copy my query and paste it in "Start" method in batch - since my query uses "accountContactRelationIdsMap" 
Should i declare accountContactRelationIdsMap in start method ?

Comment: Simply have your batchable accept the list of objects in the constructor, generate the map and store it as a (private) class attribute. This is then accessible when start is called, and can be used in the query locator returned by `start`.

Comment: BTW, what you added in your comment you should have added into the question itself as I suggested by simply [editing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/322233/edit) it.

Comment: Done - so your telling me to write query in start method as **return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id, FAB_AccountBill__c, FAB_AccountOrder__c FROM FAB_Order_Bill_Price__c');**  then in execute just copy past my method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, your issue is knowing how to create the map used in the query.

Batchables can contain class attributes like any other Apex class. These values are available for use in the `start`, `execute` and `finish` method implementations, even without implementing `Database.Stateful` (the latter allows the values of these attributes to be updated in any of these methods otherwise they get their original value each time, set when you called `Database.executeBatch`).

In this scenario it makes sense for your batchable to receive the records in its constructor, perhaps like:

```
class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<FAB_Order_Bill_Price__c> {
    private Map<Id, List<Id>> accountContactRelationIdsMap = new Map<Id, List<Id>>();

    public MyBatch(List<AccountContactRelation> oldRelations, List<AccountContactRelation> relations) {
        // In here do the processing to initialize the accountContactRelationIdsMap
        // using the "oldRelations" and "relations" (which would actually be given the
        // Trigger.old and Trigger.new arrays where you construct the batch and execute
        // it, from within the trigger)
    }
```

You can now use the map in the query locator returned by the `start` method basically the same way you already do in your for loop.

As mentioned above, you construct the batch with the trigger old and new data in the trigger, thus:

```
Database.executeBatch(new MyBatch(Trigger.old, Trigger.new));
```

Comment: In this case how to execute my batch ? - i mean which parameters should i use in **Database.executeBatch(new MyBatch(?,?));** 
i will try to copy the first loop and paste it inside the constructor **MyBatch**

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: If you do it right it will work

Comment: Please don't think of this as just a copy and paste operation. There is at least a little bit of restructuring you'll need to perform on your code. Between Phil's great answer and Trailhead you should have a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: @PhilW ,  my purpose is how to covert `String oldRoles = (Trigger.isUpdate) ? ((AccountContactRelation) Trigger.oldMap.get(accountContactRelation.Id)).Roles : null;`  with **oldRelations** &  **relations** parameters in my batch

Comment: Do whatever conversion you need outside the batch, have the batch accept, as constructor arguments, whatever data it needs to use in the required query selector and store it, as attributes in the class, appropriately for reference in that query selector.